# pandas dataframe label comparision on the basis of primary identifier

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, compare

let's say we have first dataframe (df1) as

```
t_ent_id,calendar_date,instrument_id,sector,flag
423342,2020-03-11 00:00:00,apple,healthcare,y
544442,2020-03-11 00:00:00,Microsoft,software,y
772222,2020-03-11 00:00:00,amazon,IT,y
986554,2020-03-11 00:00:00,yahoo,IT,n
423342,2020-03-12 00:00:00,apple,healthcare,y
544442,2020-03-12 00:00:00,Microsoft,software,y
772222,2020-03-12 00:00:00,amazon,IT,y
986554,2020-03-12 00:00:00,yahoo,IT,n
```

and second dataframe as

```
t_ent_id,calendar_date,instrument_id,sector,flag
423342,2020-03-11 00:00:00,apple,health,y
544442,2020-03-11 00:00:00,Microsoft,software,y
772222,2020-03-11 00:00:00,amazon,IT,n
986554,2020-03-11 00:00:00,yahoo,mail,n
423342,2020-03-12 00:00:00,apple,healthcare,y
544442,2020-03-12 00:00:00,Microsoft,software,y
772222,2020-03-12 00:00:00,amazon,IT,y
986554,2020-03-12 00:00:00,yahoo,IT,n
```

I wanted to compare both dataframe (labels) row by row on the basis of primary identifier i.e. `t_ent_id,calendar_date`

like

```
    423342,2020-03-11 00:00:00,apple,healthcare,y  #df1    
    423342,2020-03-11 00:00:00,apple,health,y      #df2
```

if remining label are mismatched then it throw both the rows with
 mismatched rows

```
    423342,2020-03-11 00:00:00,apple,healthcare,y      
    423342,2020-03-11 00:00:00,apple,health,y
```

I tried below method, pls suggest some better alternative

```
df_f =pd.merge(df_1,df_2,how='outer',left_on=['t_ent_id','calendar_date','instrument_id','sector','flag'],right_on=['t_ent_id','calendar_date','instrument_id','sector','flag'],indicator=True)
print(df_f)
diff = df_f[df_f['_merge']!='both']
diff.sort_values(by=['calendar_date','t_ent_id'])
```

expected output

[image]

Comment: Not clear what is needed. What is the expected output?

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, use `duplicated` with `drop_duplicates`:

```
df = pd.concat([df1,df2])
res = df[df.duplicated(subset=["t_ent_id", "calendar_date"], keep=False)].drop_duplicates()
res = res.sort_values(["t_ent_id", "calendar_date"])
print(res)
```

Output:

```
   t_ent_id        calendar_date instrument_id      sector flag
0    423342  2020-03-11 00:00:00         apple  healthcare    y
0    423342  2020-03-11 00:00:00         apple      health    y
4    423342  2020-03-12 00:00:00         apple  healthcare    y
1    544442  2020-03-11 00:00:00     Microsoft    software    y
5    544442  2020-03-12 00:00:00     Microsoft    software    y
2    772222  2020-03-11 00:00:00        amazon          IT    y
2    772222  2020-03-11 00:00:00        amazon          IT    n
6    772222  2020-03-12 00:00:00        amazon          IT    y
3    986554  2020-03-11 00:00:00         yahoo          IT    n
3    986554  2020-03-11 00:00:00         yahoo        mail    n
7    986554  2020-03-12 00:00:00         yahoo          IT    n
```

Answer (score 0):

Use, `boolean masking` along with [`pd.concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) and [`sort_values`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html):

```
d1 = df1[df1.ne(df2).any(axis=1)]
d2 = df2[df2.ne(df1).any(axis=1)]
df = pd.concat([d1, d2]).sort_values(by=['t_ent_id','calendar_date'])
```

---

```
# print(df)

   t_ent_id        calendar_date instrument_id      sector flag
0    423342  2020-03-11 00:00:00         apple  healthcare    y
0    423342  2020-03-11 00:00:00         apple      health    y
2    772222  2020-03-11 00:00:00        amazon          IT    y
2    772222  2020-03-11 00:00:00        amazon          IT    n
3    986554  2020-03-11 00:00:00         yahoo          IT    n
3    986554  2020-03-11 00:00:00         yahoo        mail    n
```